# How do I fix this Azure publishing error?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, azure, certificate, publish

## **Problem**

Up until this week I have been successfully publishing services to Azure.
But this morning, when I went to do a publish, I was greeted with the following screen:
http://postimg.org/image/fyno8sxpl/. If I mouse over the red crosses, the hint says: "One or more errors occurred".

If I click 'Publish' it shows the following message but nothing else happens:
http://postimg.org/image/jwb7onbdv/

My colleagues have (what appears to be) exactly the same setup but they do not see any errors. I suspect it is something to do with certificates, but I cannot find any invalid or out of date certificates.

Has anyone here encountered a similar issue and are able to point me in the right direction?

Thank you for any help you can provide.

*Extra info:
I am using Windows7 / VS Professional 2012 / C#.*

```
I have found the solution...
```

## **Solution**

1. Select 'Publish' in your project.
2. Select 'Previous' until you are at the first tab.
3. Select `<Manage...>` from the 'Choose your subscription' dropdown.
4. Click 'Sign out'.
5. Click 'Sign in'.
6. Select 'Sign out and sign in with another account'
7. Finally, sign in with your usual account.

Comment: I have found the solution! 
Just in case anyone else has the same problem, the solution is to:
1) Select 'Publish' in your project.
2) Select 'Previous' until you are at the first tab.
3) Select '<Manage...>' from the 'Choose your subscription' dropdown.
4) Click 'Sign out'.
5) Click 'Sign in'.
6) Select 'Sign out and sign in with another account'
7) Finally, sign in with your usual account.

Comment: Thank you this also worked for me, very frustrating that it doesn't give you more information.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting this error you may need to re enter your credentials for Azure.

If you go to **Server Explorer** there will be a yellow warning sign on the top menu item.
You can right click on it and reenter your credentials.

[image]

Reference:
http://www.anujchaudhary.com/2015/09/one-or-more-errors-occurred-while.html